# Shortcode not working after move wordpress website files

Tags: plugins, shortcode

After I migrate the existing wordpress website files in public_html, the all new plugins installed, there shorcode are not working anymore on any pages.

Here's the page that I put a shortcode from newly installed plugin
http://www.homecredit.ph/2590-2

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the page it shows as `[vfb id=’1′]`

But, when I view source code, it shows as `[vfb id=&#8217;1&#8242;]`

Look again at the code on the actual page - one mark is a right single quotation mark (8217) and the other character is called a 'prime' (8242).

Try removing the punctuation marks so it's just `[vfb id=1]` (best to use 'Text' view in editor window for this).

Comment: try your suggestion, but still not working

Comment: Your page code suggests you're still editing this using the Layout view when you should be using the [Text view - example](http://imgur.com/hKUhd6r). Try that first with single and then double quotes. 
If it still doesn't work, try the [Wordpress plugins support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-visual-form-builder-shortcode) or contact the plugin vendor directly for support.